# react-table how create column headers and cells with array

Tags: reactjs, react-table

i'm using react-table in my project and i wonder how create headers dynamically with array.

in my component i have:

```
const columns = [
  {Header: 'day', accessor: ''}, 
  {Header: 'day', accessor: ''}
]

<ReactTable
    className="-striped -highlight"
    data={this.props.items}
    columns={columns}
    defaultPageSize={20}/>
```

and i have json data like that:

```
"items": [
    {
      "day": "01",
      "city": "A",
      "1": "",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": null,
      "5": "",
      "6": 256,
      "7": 36.07,
      "8": 35.15,
      "9": "",
      "10": "",
      "11": 6.49,
      "12": 5.9,
      "13": "",
      "14": "",
      "15": 72.0,
      "16": 62.109375,
      "17": 266.78,
      "18": 83.59375,
      "19": 444.96
    },
    {
      "day": "02",
      "city": "B",
      "1": "",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": null,
      "5": "",
      "6": 234,
      "7": 36.52,
      "8": 35.6,
      "9": "",
      "10": "",
      "11": 6.08,
      "12": 5.71,
      "13": "",
      "14": "",
      "15": 64.0,
      "16": 43.162393162393165,
      "17": 121.97,
      "18": 84.1880341880342,
      "19": 346.49
    },
    {
      "day": "03",
      "city": "B",
      "1": "",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": null,
      "5": "",
      "6": 221,
      "7": 36.96,
      "8": 35.93,
      "9": "",
      "10": "",
      "11": 5.82,
      "12": 5.28,
      "13": "",
      "14": "",
      "15": 56.99999999999999,
      "16": 39.366515837104075,
      "17": 94.48,
      "18": 78.28054298642535,
      "19": 227.4
    },
   ]
```

so here is i want to make each item in items array will have column. and these columns headers will be their day property and cells will be values which in list 1, 2, 3, 5, 6. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just have a loop in a function to dynamically create the headers you need based on the first object of your `items` list :

```
getColumns () {
  let columns = [];
  let headers = Object.keys(items[0]);
  headers.forEach(header => {
    columns.push({
      Header: header
      accessor: ""
    })
  }

  return columns;
}
```

Hope it is what you were looking for (unless I didn't understand the question).

**UPDATE**

The first thing to do is to build the rows array to fit the way you want to display them. Indeed, the `items` array should be transformed into something like this :

```
[{
  "day01": "A",
  "day02": "B",
  "day03": "B"
},
{...}]
```

It can be done like this :

```
  render () {
    const rows = this.buildDataFromItems(items);   // items is your json array
    const columns = this.buildColumnsFromItems(items);
    return(
      <ReactTable
        columns={columns}
        data={rows}
      />
    )
  }

  buildColumnsFromItems (items) {
    let headers = [];
    items.forEach(item => {
      headers.push("day" + item.day);
    })

    let columns = [];
    headers.forEach(header => {
      columns.push({
        Header: header,
        accessor: header
      })
    });

    return columns;
  }

  buildDataFromItems (items) {
    let rows = [];
    let currentHeader = "";
    let currentRow = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(items[0]).length && Object.keys(items[0])[i] !== "day"; i++) {
      currentRow = {};
      items.forEach(item => {
        currentHeader = "day" + item.day;
        currentRow[currentHeader] = item[Object.keys(items[0])[i]];
      })

      rows.push(currentRow);
    }

    return rows;
  }
```

This piece of code should be enough to lead you to your final solution I hope :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry for my bad explanation. I want to make each column will take one item in array so column header will be day01 property and from top to bottom will ordered another values. order will be like in json data, just each column will take one item in this array. From top to bottom, another item will be another column, next item will be another..

Comment: Ooh so you want actually the header to be the first attribute of each item ? Like first column has header `day01` with values listed below, then second header is `day02` etc ? Then, as a value, what do you wish to display ? the keys concatenated to their values (ex: `cityB`) or just the given value ? (ex: `B`)

Comment: yes header will be 'day' and cell values of this column will be "1": "",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": null,
      "5": "",
      "6": 221,
      "7": 36.96,
      "8": 35.93,
      "9": "",
      "10": "",
      "11": 5.82,
      "12": 5.28,
      "13": "",
      "14": "",
      "15": 56.99999999999999,
      "16": 39.366515837104075,
      "17": 94.48,
      "18": 78.28054298642535,
      "19": 227.4 , from top to bottom

Comment: @user3348410 I added a piece of code to match the rows construction that needs to be done, based on your `items` array. Tell me if this is clear for you ! :)

Comment: thanks you so much! it's worked well and i understand the concept :)